# how to open xterm in mininet after you execute a python script as root user?

Tags: networking, xterm, mininet, sdn

I am running a python script and when I execute it as normal user mininet says

```
must run as root
```

and when I execute it as root user it works fine but after the script I have to open xterm h1 and it doesn't allow if you are a root user.

How to open xterm as a root user?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo -E python <name of the custom topo file>
```

This would let you to run the custom topo script as a script. Then you should be able to use xtrem.

[Tutorial link](https://github.com/Ehsan70/SDN/blob/master/Simple_Mininet_tutorial.md)